# Error with file pointer not defined

Tags: c, linux, pointers, file-pointer

I have a file `a.c`, `a.h` which acts as a supporting module with functions from other files.

In those functions I have to open a file and do functions like reading data, writing data, closing it.

For these purposes I gave a global declaration for file pointer in `a.c` by

```
static FILE* pFile;
```

and used `pFile` directly.

The error that the compiler was throwing error is like :

```
"pFile" not defined in the function
```

What's wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define path "/tmp/diag.log"

FILE* pFile;

void a(bool value) {
    if (value) {
            pFile = fopen (path,"a");
      return;
    }
    else if (!value) {
        fclose (pFile);
    }
}

void b(bool value) {
  if(value)
  {
  fprintf (pFile,"%s",message);
  }
  }
```

Update: 
The error was my makefile was taking the files from build directory and the changes were not getting reflected.Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Do you understand the need and effect of the `static` storage class?

Comment: hehe...that was a mistake..kindly help me in this

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as the actual error messages (in full, complete and without modifications) as text.

Comment: yeah..like it will be initialized only once during compilation..i tried normal way intially but even then it was not workin

Comment: If the static definition is in `a.c` and the functions that try to use it are also in `a.c`, there should be no problem as long as you defined it before you used it.  If you try to use it outside of `a.c`, it will fail.  The static variable should not be present in the header; that will give trouble.  Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) and the compilation and linking commands your are using.

Comment: thank you for the edit Jonathan..they are in the same file but still I m not able to clear this error.kindly help me in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to use this `static FILE* pFile` from another compilation units remove the `static`

in other file add:

```
 extern FILE *pfile;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply...I have removed static but still it is throwing pFile not defined error..I have declared File* pFile in the same a.c under the macros and this file only consists of functions...should i declare it elsewhere?once again thank you for the reply

Comment: Hi..I have added the code which resemble my implementation  for your  kind peruse..should i add in the files calling this function...i m not able to understand as this should be local to this file rite?

Comment: @Ram show exact compiler output - all errors and warnings

Comment: It is of no use to answer these questions that lack a proper [mcve]. It just gets the site filled with more c**p.

Comment: @Ram it is definitely not the complete output

Comment: No peter the only errors i am receiving are these 2 and it stops the compilation and comes out of project directories...

Comment: The error was my makefile was taking the files from build directory and the changes were not getting reflected.Thanks a lot for your help